# Using strip_tags() and preg_replace() to display text entered in a WYSIWYG/TinyMCE Text Editior

Tags: php, javascript, html

Good morning,

Here's the problem:
I have some text being entered in via text editor (WYSIWYG/TinyMCE) and being displayed elsewhere as posting.  The problem we have is that the text looses its formatting when being displayed as a posting.  After digging through the code, I discovered that this was being done with a strip_tags() + echo preg_replace() combo.  I'm still new to PHP, but I was able to figure out:

- strip_tags() was taking out the formatting (b/c that's how it rolls)
- I could add  and  to get the bold and italicized text to display
- the underlined and strikethrough text are CSS styles and adding the code (as it is saved on the db table) to the strip_tags() list did NOT solve the problem

My question is: can I modify the existing code to solve this, or should I use something else (htmlentities() perhaps)?

EDIT: I tried htmlentities and it failed.
EDIT: I added just the  tag and the problem is 50% solved.  My text is underlined, but it shows lower than the non-underlined text that comes after it.  Its as if the underlined text is being treated as subtext or something.

code snippet:

```
    <div class="display_text_area">
        <?php $text = strip_tags(str_ireplace("</p>", "</p><br/>", 
              $text_detail->description),
              '<font><ul><li><br/><strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;">'); ?>
        <?php echo preg_replace('/(<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/', '<br/>', $text); ?>
    </div>
```

I'm leaving the  tag here to show that (a) I tried it, and (b) it didn't work.  So (c) I know it needs to be removed or modified.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that TinyMCE returns *nominally* valid rich HTML that doesn't need stripping or escaping before being used in an HTML page.  *However*, you can't assume that the TinyMCE editor is running on the client, as a you might be exploited by someone who simply directly posts a response which contains an XSS attack.

IIRC, TinyMCE returns XHTML by default.  You need to ensure that any returned HTML is correct using a library such as HTML Purifier.

Comment: I came across HTML purifier in my searches, I will give it a try.

Comment: Use the `[htmlpurifier]` tag in your searches here to see more related Q&As on how to use it.

Comment: I'm having some issues with the install, and I don't really have the time to figure out this install issue right now as our code is live now and I need to get the issue in the question FIXED.  I might be able to use this later.

Comment: The easiest "answer" is to use the raw post content as a short term workaround, but you will be opening yourself up to XSS attack, so you need to back-fit the purifier ASAP.

Comment: Installing the purifier was not an easy task for me.  Due to my relatively low PHP experience.  And it should be something simple, but I struggled mightily yesterday to try and to get it in.  I posted on the support boards on the site and they were responsive, but no progress.  I'm going to try a hidden read-only TinyMCE window and then use JS to pull the text out of it and display that.  What do you think of that as a temporary solution (or is that essentially what you are suggesting), TerryE?

Comment: I use TinyMCE on my [blog](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/), but I wrote my engine partly for my own pleasure, and partly because I didn't like the performance and editing facilities of WordPress.  I didn't get to grips with HTML purifier, but wrote my own purifier which was heavily influenced by the TinyMCE one.  If you are only offering rich text editing to trusted (e.g. known logged-one) users then XSS isn't a material risk and not purifying server-side might be an option that you want to consider for more than a short term solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13522/discussion-between-waddler-and-terrye)